# Recuperar dados do firebase com múltiplos parâmetros

Tags: android, firebase

Estou tentando recuperar um nó do firebase, porem esse ele precisa atender dois parâmetros, data inicial e data final. O nó fica da forma me passaram uma opção seria colocar mais um valor para **date_start_end : 1478484000_1478397600**, so que com isso não da para buscar entre as datas. Isso não seria uma opção viável.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu também tinha tentando usar so que o firebase não da suporte a mais de uma orderBy

`.orderByChild("date_start").startAt(mDay).endAt(mDay)
 .orderByChild("date_end").startAt(mDay).endAt(mDay);`

isso leva o error de

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You can't combine multiple orderBy calls!`

Alguma sugestão para resolver esse questão?

Answer (score 1):

[Da documentação](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) :

> You can only use one order-by method at a time. Calling an order-by method multiple times in the same query throws an error.

Então por isso você tem um erro.

Talvez haja um problema na forma em que você estruturou essa query, pois você quer filtrar registros que começaram entre `mDay` e `mDay` e todos que terminaram em `mDay` e `mDay`. O que você necessita ? ver todos que começaram e acabaram no mesmo dia ?

Não seria melhor buscar por registros que começaram entre uma data e outra e exibir a data em que terminaram ? Ou listar todos que acabaram entre uma data e outra e listar quando começaram ?

Algo como : `.orderByChild("date_start").startAt(07112016).endAt(07122016);` ( Não sei como você está organizando essa data)

Comment: a data está em timestamp, a minha intenção seria buscar os registro que estão entre as datas de inicio(date_start ) e final (date_end) o myDay corresponde ao timestamp do dia. A query que eu preciso montar seria para resolver o seguinte situação :
Pegar um ou n registro que estejam entre a data de inicio e a data final, baseado na data atual.
Em sql seria algo parecido com isso:
`SELECT users.id, DATE_FORMAT(users.signup_date, '%Y-%m-%d') 
    FROM users 
    WHERE signup_date >= CURDATE() && signup_date < (CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY) `

Comment: Então, no caso você possuí um único campo "signup_date" e está filtrando utilizando ele. Então a lógica é `signup_date > data atual  && signup_date < data limite` certo ? Transformando pro Firebase seria algo como `.orderByChild("signup_date").startAt(dataAtual).endAt(dataLimite);`

Comment: eu entendi o que você colocou ai, e o código que  você fez faz total sentido. Porem quando eu tenho que comparar entre dos filhos como no exemplo da pergunta. Compara a data entre  o nó filho date_start e o nó filho date_end em relação ao dia atual<myDay>. Isso seria possível?

Comment: No Firebase, não é possível buscar por duas "keys", acredito que se você quer fazer uma busca nas duas Childs, terá que fazer programaticamente (Fazendo uma query, e depois filtrando essa query com o outro dado) ou criar um índice que combine os dois, o problema é que por se tratar de datas acho que não vai servir ao seu propósito.

Comment: vlw pela ajuda, realmente não irá me ajudar, o intuito disso seria reduzir a quantidade de itens a serem recuperados do lado do server(firebase). Infelizmente terei que buscar tudo e filtrar na hora de exibir, mas vlw a força.

Comment: @JeffersonRodriguesdosSantos, por nada, eu sei que ao usar o Firebase com Javascript você consegue fazer uma query no retorno da outra, não sei se no Android é possível, se quiser dar uma [olhada](http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/SSnfr/)

Comment: dependendo da aplicação se for rodar em angular 2 o David East fez um biblioteca para isso, infelizmente não tem ara java ou swift da uma olhada la ai ta bem legal. [https://github.com/davideast/Querybase]